# Is it possible to cascade delete a column value?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, delete, cascade

So say I delete `catID` from table A and table B has the same foreign key value? It's hard to explain so I'll try and show you with the two images below:

### items table

[image: This catID is referencing a category from the category table]

Is it possible to delete the `catID` from the above table `(items)` when I delete on cascade a value from the below table `(categories)`:

### Categories  table:

[image]

So say I ran `delete from categories where catID = 1` - This will delete both rows from both tables? So essentially it would delete the whole `iID` instead of just the `catID` value?

Is it possible to have it delete only the value from the `catID` column in the items table?

If I'm not making any sense, please let me know? As I'm finding it kind of hard to explain!!